# Extjs4 what's the best way to add a plugin in extjs?

Tags: plugins, extjs4

I want to add a plugin(http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150918-Grid-Header-Filters) to my application.

What's the best way to install it, considering I use sencha SDK-tools ...
The class name of plugin is: Ext.ux.grid.plugin.HeaderFilters

Any suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Check basic setup  here:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/html-page-setup/

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Velociraptor Owners</title>
<!--Ext JS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<!-- script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/bootstrap.js"></script-->
<script src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script src="extjs/GridHeaderFilters.js"></script>
<!--Application JS-->
<script src="grid.js"></script>
<!-- script src="php/api.php"></script -->
<!--Application Aesthetics-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```